# A reference for Calculus of Functors for Model Categories

Tags: calculus-of-functors, reference-request, model-categories, homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology

I am wondering where I might look to see what has been done in terms of Calculus of Functors for more general weak equivalences and Model Categories.

I am at least aware of some of the extended definitions of the main concepts in Calculus of Functors to weak equivalence such as homotopy limits, but I was wondering if a document existed that worked through the basic of COF in this setting.

I am aware also of Lurie's work [here.](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/GoodwillieI.pdf)(Thanks Harry for pointing this out.)

I appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't think I agree with the addition of those two tags, but it matters little to me, so I will leave them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Calculus III and its predecessors I studied functors from Top to Top and a few related cases. The ideas clearly generalize to functors $C\to D$ between model categories satisfying some pretty weak axioms, but I did not try to find the right axioms, and I don't think anyone has ever written anything definitive about that.

Is that what you are asking about?

The paper mentioned by Tilson takes the ideas in a somewhat different direction, I think: it's about treating the categories of functors themselves as model categories and finding Quillen adjoint pairs that refine my ideas.

Comment: @Tom This is exactly what I was looking for. I was hoping to "model"(ha ha) the style of the Goodwillie Calculus on Homotopy equivalences, to more general weak equivalences on some model categories. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I haven't read it, but maybe this could be useful: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601221
Calculus of Functors and Model categories by Biedermann Chorny and Roendigs

Comment: Thanks, I did know of this, and forgot to put it in my question. It is in the direction I am wondering though, so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You might look at Thomas Goodwillie's papers "Calculus I" (*K-Theory*, 4), "Calculus II" (*K-Theory*, 5) and "Calculus III" (*Geometry and Topology*, 7).

Answer (score 2):

You might look at http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.1919 "On calculus of functors in model categories, Stanculescu"